# Fragment display different content

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Can I make a Fragment to display different content depending on what was selected in the previous screen.

For example: I create Fragment with ImageView and TextView. In MainActivity I click Button1 and the Fragment opens and shows some content, and if I click Button2 the same Fragment opens but different content is displayed. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You just need to pass a flag via bundle (arguments) and the fragment decides what to do next.

Comment: Can you explain this more clearly or link the documentation for me?

Comment: I add an answer for more detail

Comment: It would be better If you use 2 different fragments for better code readability. Otherwise flag will do the work. Based on flag, You can inflate different layouts in your fragment

Comment: I am a complete newbie. Can you explain how to do this in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: If the fragment instance is not retained/reused (for example, fragment dialog), we just need to bind flag/content via arguments when creating that fragment

```
fun createAFragment(flag: Int): Fragment {
    val fragment = AFragment()
    fragment.arguments = Bundle().apply { putString("keyFlag", flag) }
    return fragment
}
```

Inside AFragment's `onViewCreated()`, we can read the flag value from `arguments` bundle and bind equivalent data into image view and text view.
We can also bind the image resource and text to the fragment via the `arguments` too (see [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle))

We can apply this approach for fragments on [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) too.

Case 2: The fragment instance is retained, for example, two fragments on an activity, 1 controls the another.
In this case, we should use [view model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to share data between fragments and activity, [live data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) for notifying data change.

This codelab might be helpful for learning about ViewModel and LiveData: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data